# How do I get the elastic load balancer dns name?

Tags: terraform

I've created an elastic beanstalk environment through terraform.  I'd like to add a route53 record pointing at the load balancer's dns but I can't figure out how to get the full url from the outputs of the EB environment.

The aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.xxx.load_balancers property contains the *name* but not the FQDN.

Comment: Actually, maybe I should be pointing at the cname, which is in the environment outputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have created both beanstalk resources like so

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "eb_app" {
    name = "eb_app"
    description = "some description"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "eb_env" {
    name = "eb_env"
    application = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.eb_app.name}"
    solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.3 running Go 1.4"
    setting {
        namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
        name      = "VPCId"
        value     = "something"
    }

    setting {
        namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
        name      = "Subnets"
        value     = "somethingelse"
    }
}
```

The documentation included [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_beanstalk_environment.html) specifies that you can use 'cname' to output the fully qualified DNS name for the environment

To do that you would write something like

```
output "cname" {
  value = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.eb_env.cname}"
}
```

Then, in the same directory that you invoked the module, you could

```
cname_to_pass_to_route53 = "${module.some_eb_module.cname}"
```

If the cname is not the exact verision of the url that you need, you could append or prepend the variable name when passing it in.  It does say fully qualified DNS name though, so I don't think you'd need to do that.

```
cname_to_pass_to_route53 = "maybeHere://${module.some_eb_module.cname}/orOverHere"
```

Comment: That's a more detailed version of my comment, but I'll give you the points for effort!